# SQL - Join two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables

**Users:** (id, name)

**Relations:** (user_id, relation_id)

User_id and relation_id are both ids from the table `users`.

What I want is ro recover all users who are friend with a specific user.

And here is my sql command: that doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
NATURAL JOIN relations
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE name='John doe');
```

Could you help me?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users JOIN relations on id = user_id WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE name='John doe');`

Comment: How to tell if someone is friend with other? I get it is in relations table, but what is the logic behind it?

Comment: Thanks but the name it gives me is always John doe...

Comment: @Vodemki I believe most answers are wrong, because people mixed up `relation_id` and `user_id`. Try my answer, it should work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT users.*
FROM relations
INNER JOIN users
  ON relations.relation_id = users.id
WHERE relations.user_id = 12345;
```

You can also get the id with a subquery, just as you did in your example:

```
WHERE relations.user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE name='John doe');
```

Answer (score 2):

To get all the relations a person has , the following query will work..

SELECT * FROM users us JOIN relations re ON us.id = re.relation_id 
WHERE re.user_id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM users
    WHERE name = 'John doe'
)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM users as a 
JOIN relations as b on a.id = b.user_id 
WHERE b.user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE name='John doe')
```

Comment: @Vodemki share you sample data and desired result, then i can help you further

Comment: Thanks but Shedal gave me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id
FROM relations re
JOIN users us
ON us.id = re.user_id
WHERE relation_id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM users
    WHERE name = 'John Doe'
)
```

Side note: you can't use `NATURAL JOIN` here, 'cause there is no column that have the same name and type in the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

isnt this just a matter of querying the relations tables by the userId you are looking for?

```
select * 
from relations
where  user_id = @IdYouArelookingFor or relation_id = @IdYouArelookingFor
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT friend.*
FROM users AS friend
  JOIN relations AS r
    ON r.relation_id = friend.id
  JOIN users AS u 
    ON u.id = r.user_id
WHERE u.name = 'John doe' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Friends are people with the same relation_id?

```
SELECT a.name FROM users a JOIN relations b on a.id = b.user_id
WHERE b.relation_id in 
(select relation_id from relations where id = 'userid of user you are looking for') 
AND a.id !=  'userid of user you are looking for'
```

If your logic is different pls tell how it is working